# How to have website in subdirectory, but access it from the root? (Ex: Prestashop, Wordpress)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, prestashop, root, subdirectory

**Problem:** I have a prestashop in mydomain.ee/prestashop_subdir

**Expected:** I want to access mydomain.ee so my website (Prestashop) works from the root. But prestashop is still in subdirectory. Same should apply to admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution (replace domain and dir names to yours):**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.ee$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prestashop_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /prestashop_subdir/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.ee$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ prestashop_subdir/index.php [L]
```

**Hint:** These lines mean that this redirection should be done not always, but only when file or directory is missing:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```